# Can divorce happen in the absence of his wife?

Tags: talaq

If a man says **divorce/talaq** three times silently (in the absence of his wife), does it become divorce?

Comment: Does he *intend* to give divorce?

Comment: Not verbally, in his silent mind, it can be intended or not. His wife completely does not know. And he does not express it in front of his wife.

Comment: Talaq must be uttered else how would anybody, especially the wofe know she was divorced. Talaq is a very serious topic. Please use meaningful tags.